# How to correctly parse Json DateTime with Timezone

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to parse a datetime string from Json.

I'm saving the following date via json: `04/01/1990` - it's serializing that datetime like this: `"1990-04-01T04:00:00.000Z"`

However its returning 3/31/1990 When I then try to parse that string dob back into a datetime object like this:

```
var dob = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse(DOB, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dob);
```

I've also tried (with no luck):

```
var dob = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse(DOB, out dob);
```

I can't figure out how to correctly parse this datetime to the proper original date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET is converting the time to your local time. You can call `ToUniversalTime()` to convert it back to UTC.

Alternatively, you can use `DateTimeOffset` to keep the date relative to UTC.